# Scribus - How to get automatic sequential page numbers in split document?

Tags: page-layout, scribus, numbering

I have a book project, split in 10 files, one for each chapter. I have created them as I want them, and exported in pdf. Now, if I join the pdf files afterward, they will all have page numbers that start at 1 at the beginning of each chapter!

I have tried that, and then gone back to each chapter and changed the start of pagination for each chapter, but with many chapters, that is a very time consuming process.

Is there any way around that, except joining all the chapters before exporting the pdfs?

Thanks.

Comment: No, as far as I know, there is currently no better way to do it. But you reminded me that I wanted to have a look at the sections UI and improve it. I'm also tempted to provide access to the section through the scripting. Once it's done, it might be possible to create a "master" config file that can be used by a script to synchronize project documents. You can read [here](https://bugs.scribus.net/view.php?id=16230) about the progress.

Comment: I have since asking my question found out that joining the chapters before exporting is a no-go. The join functionality is totally broken, as linked text frames becomes unlinked. It makes the joining of text document totally useless.

Comment: it's not completely useless, but it cannot be used to manage sub projects. anyway,  i don't think that in the current state of scribus, it's a good idea to merge multitple .sla to create one big document. for now, merging the pdfs is the safe and easy way to do it.